# Changing the order of elements using absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I want to move a child element to the bottom of its parent via absolute positioning.

Ie The parent will finish and then the element will appear directly after. ie the Parents bottom margin will be aligned with the childs top margin.

I have somewhat achieved this via padding however I don't see how to make this work when the child's size is changeable? ie I have a hardcoded padding size.

```
<body>
  <footer class="footer">
    <p> I am the footer </p>
    <div class="after">
    <h2> I want to appear after the footer</h2>
     <img src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <h3> I should be in the footer</h3>
  </footer>

</body
```

css ->

```
.footer {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 500px;
}

.after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

codepen -> http://codepen.io/ianw92/pen/pvXYeV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements are removed from the normal flow. By definition, they therefore won't take other elements into consideration when being positioned. As you are seeing, you would need to hardcode some value.

I'd suggest avoiding absolute positioning and using a flexbox solution to change the order of the elements:

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwrLKp)

```
.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.footer .after {
  order: 3;
}
```

Comment: Just messing around now.. I removed all padding and set the top on .after to 100%... seems to of worked.

Comment: @IanWatson Does the `.footer` element have a hardcoded height? Wouldn't that cause it to overlap with content that appears below it?

Comment: Thanks Josh that is also a ideal solution too

Comment: @IanWatson The `.footer` element doesn't contain the absolutely positioned element though. Look at what happens when there is content under it, or even if you try to set a `background-color` on it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYMxEP

Comment: Ah I see. In this scenario because Its the footer I know there won't be anything else underneath but I see your point. 

However I don't think the flex display work on IE8 which is a requirement.

Comment: @IanWatson Yea, good point... I didn't realize people are still supporting IE8